# What does the prefix `\??\` mean in a Windows path?

Tags: windows, command-line, path

In Windows Task Manager, when displaying the Details view, there is a process `conhost.exe`, whose Command line is shown as `\??\C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe 0x4`. What does the prefix `\??\` mean?

I am aware of the prefix `\\?\`, which allows longer paths and special characters, but I assume this is something distinct.